# NLog arguments for errorException message

Tags: c#, exception, nlog

I am looking for a way to log expressive messages when I catch an exception with NLog 2.0.1, something like

```
try {
    ....
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    logger.ErrorException("Error with query {0}", query, ex);
}
```

But NLog does not support it.
Other forms that have happened to me are

```
logger.ErrorException(  String.Format("Error with query {0}", query)) , ex);
```

or

```
logger.Error("Error with query {0} {1} {2}", query, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
```

or

```
logger.Error("Error with query {0}", query);
logger.ErrorException("", ex);
```

or

```
LogEventInfo ei = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, logger.Name, null, 
                         "Error with query {0}", new object[] { query }, ex); 
logger.Log(ei);
```

But none seems so simple as calls to `logger.Error ()`
At the moment, the first option is my favority despite Format a string that maybe will not be used:

- the second option not use the layout options for [exceptions](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer).
- the third creates two entries in the log and maybe will be confusing.
- the fourth option is much less clear.

There is some more?

Comment: `String.Format("Error with query %s", query)` Is this c#?

Comment: ups.. I made out with java. Edited

Comment: Why not just write an extension method?

Answer (score 5):

Update,

This is possible since NLog 4.0

```
logger.Error(ex, "Error with query {0}", query);
```

See [news post  - consistent logging of exceptions](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/09/nlog-4-has-been-released.html)

Comment: Great feature! I don't accept the answer because it was done for NLog 2.0.1, but is good to now that the library has improved.

Comment: Sure, although I dislike unanswered questions

Answer (score 0):

There are no other overrides.  You are out of luck.

Your second example looks nice.

When I look in Visual Studio `Error()` has 42 different signatures

`ErrorException()` only has one.

From the following link you can see this: (click on "Error" and "ErrorException" links)

http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/AllMembers_T_NLog_Logger.htm